# Can a Logstash filter has its own state?

Tags: logstash

Is it possible to implement a Logstash plugin that counts the number of handled events and output the total count to a field of all events? Something like:

```
filter {
    counter{
        count => ? # an increasing counter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called t[he `metrics` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.4/plugins-filters-metrics.html).

```
filter {
  metrics {
    meter => [ 'events' ]
  }
}
```

Which will give you fields like this:

```
events.count = Total count of events.
events.rate_1m = Per second event rate in a 1 minute sliding window.
events.rate_5m = That, but 5 minute window
events.rate_15m = that, but 15 minute window
```

This will be for each worker-thread, though. So if your logstash has 4 workers, you will get 4 different sets of `events` counts. Depending on your needs, you will likely need to aggregate them some way further down the pipeline. Perhaps with [statsd](/questions/tagged/statsd).

Comment: There is also a `logstash-filter-sequence` that will present just an increasing number... but it's marked as not-thread-safe, so it doesn't work with multiple workers.